# Object literal may only specify known properties error

Tags: angular, typescript

```
export const setLighting = createAction(
  '[Ui] SET_BACKGROUND',
  props<{
    lighting: Array<{ target: LightD; value: LightE | undefined }>
  }>(),
)
```

```
readonly setBackgroundLighting$ = this.stateTheme$.pipe(
    pluck(LightD.LEFT,LightD.RIGHT ),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    map(value =>
      setLighting({
       lighting:{target:LightD.LIGHT,value}
        }),
    ),
  )
```

```
export const LightD: {
    readonly CLIGHT: "CLIGHT";
    readonly LIGHT: "LIGHT";
    readonly LEFT: "LEFT";
    readonly RIGHT: "RIGHT";
```

Showing error Type '{ target: "LIGHT"; value: unknown; }' is not assignable to type '{ target: LightD; value: LightE| undefined; }[]'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'target' does not exist in type '{ target: LightD; value: LightE | undefined; }[]'.ts(2322)
The expected type comes from property 'lighting' which is declared here on type '{ lighting: { target: LightD; value: LightE| undefined; }[]; }'

Comment: On what line of your code snippets does this error occur?

Comment: In setBackgroundLighting$ at target:LightD

Comment: try this: map((value: LightE | undefined) =>

Comment: readonly setBackgroundLighting$ = ...(
    pluck(LightD.LEFT,LightD.RIGHT ),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    map((value: LightEffect | undefined) =>
      setLighting({
       lighting:{target:LightD.LIGHT,value}

.This is causing an error at distinctUntilChanged() :
Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, LightEffect | undefined>'.
  Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<LightEffect | undefined>'.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'LightEffect | undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `lighting` is defined as an array, so you should do this:

```js
readonly setBackgroundLighting$ = this.stateTheme$.pipe(
    pluck(LightD.LEFT,LightD.RIGHT ),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    map((value: LightE) =>
      setLighting({
       lighting:[{target:LightD.LIGHT,value}]
        }),
    ),
  )
```

Second of all are you sure the definition of `LightD` is correct? I would assume you are looking for an `enum` and not an object containing string values?

```js
enum LightD {
    CLIGHT = "CLIGHT",
    LIGHT = "LIGHT",
    LEFT = "LEFT",
    RIGHT = "RIGHT"
}
```

Comment: Tried this but gives an error at "value" in line
 ```
lighting:[{target:LightD.LIGHT,value}]

``` . Error is Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'LightEffect | undefined'

Comment: Definition of LightD is correct.

Comment: You probably need to type value correctly. (See my edit) I am not actually sure if this is the best approach. It would be cleaner to type `this.stateTheme$` correctly, but I don't know if `pluck` correctly transfers the types.